# Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause in Prolog

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I have the following error  in Prolog: "Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause" This error in the lines of declaration  procedure triangulo, circulo and rectangulo, this is my code:

```
areas:- nl,

display('1.Area triangulo'),nl,
display('2.Area circulo'),nl,
display('3.Area rectangulo'),nl,
display('4.Salir'),nl,
display('Escoja opcion:        '),nl,
read(X),opcion(X),

opcion(4).
opcion(X):-X=1,triangulo(W),areas;X=2,circulo(W),areas;X=3,rectangulo(W),areas.

triangulo(W):- write('INgresa base'),nl,
    read(B),nl,
       display('INgresa altura'),nl,
    read(A),nl,
areaT(B,A,R),nl,
    display('EL area del triangulo es: '), display(R),nl,nl,
areaT(B,A,R):-R is(B*A)/2.

circulo(W):- display('INgresa radio de circulo'),nl,
    read(RA),nl,


    areaC(RA,R),nl,
    display('EL area del CIRCULO ES: '), display(R),nl,nl,
    areaC(B,A,R):-R is(RA*RA*3.14).

rectangulo(W):- display('INgresa base'),nl,
    read(B),nl,
       display('INgresa altura'),nl,
    read(A),nl,
areaT(B,A,R),nl,
    display('EL area del rectangulo es: '), display(R),nl,nl,
areaT(B,A,R):-R is(B*A).
```

Answer (score 1):

I can spot 2 problems (copy & paste, probably):

```
...
areaT(B,A,R),nl,
    display('EL area del triangulo es: '), display(R),nl,nl,
areaT(B,A,R):-R is(B*A)/2.
...
```

and here

```
...
areaT(B,A,R),nl,
    display('EL area del rectangulo es: '), display(R),nl,nl,
areaT(B,A,R):-R is(B*A).
...
```

should be

```
..., display(R),nl,nl.
```